# Can't access my device via SSH over internet

Tags: kali-linux, routing, remote

I'm running sshdroid server on my android device at port 22 and I get this while I use my pc to connect to it via ssh (LAN)

```
root@kali:~# ssh -l root 100.107.219.116
The authenticity of host '100.107.219.116 (100.107.219.116)' can't be established. 
RSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx­xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '100.107.219.116' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
SSHDroid
Use 'root' as username
Default password is 'admin'
root@100.107.219.116­'s password: 
root@android:/data/­data/­berserker.android.app­s.sshdroid/home #
```

now when I try to access it via ssh (INTERNET)

```
root@kali:~# ssh -l root x.xx.xx.xxx
ssh: connect to host x.xx.xx.xxx port 22: No route to host 
root@kali:~#
```

so I tried to scan the ports in my external via nmap and got this as output..

```
root@kali:~# nmap x.xx.xx.xxx
Starting Nmap 6.47 (http://nmap.org/) at 2015-09-29 16:30 IST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn 
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.13 seconds 
root@kali:~# nmap -Pn x.xx.xx.xxx

Starting Nmap 6.47 (http://nmap.org/) at 2015-09-29 16:30 IST

Nmap scan report for x.xx.xx.xxx
Host is up (0.11s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 1-39-60-154.live.vod­afone.in (x.xx.xx.xxx) are filtered
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.77 seconds 

root@kali:~#
```

I'm using DIR-600M router. How can I connect to my device via ssh over internet?

Comment: Do you use a firewall ?

Comment: I disabled it since it would block the connection

Comment: Are you sure that your device has real IP address, not behind NAT? "No route to host" kind of suggests your IP is not good.

Comment: Is x.xx.xx.xxx the address of your dlink, your android device, or something else?

Comment: its my external ip of the router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Archemar said, you must forward port 22 to one of your machines. The router can't assume you want a port forwarded, even if only one machine stands behind the router. The default is to block everything, which is wise from a security perspective.

AFAIK, this means

- Assigning one static local IP to each machine you want a port forwarded to. If you use DHCP, you'll be doing this in the router configuration interface by attributing an IP to the machine's MAC address (that is, to its network interface MAC address).
- Forwarding port 22 to the static IP of your choice.

You didn't ask, but if you want to ssh to several machines on your local network, you can do so by using non-standard ports, one for each machine.

Comment: i have a **doubt**.i use my another android mobile to tether internet over usbto my pc. the pc is connected to the DIR-600M router (nota modem).when i connect to internet i was assigned an ip address.is this ip address the external ip address of the router too?or this is the main **cause** for all the problems i have?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup, but it seems uncommon. You may want to edit your question and add a precise description of it.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably multiple host behind your router (for instance you android).

The router has no way of knowing where to send incomming ssh packet (*), or if you accept them at all.

You have to tell your router what to do (to which IP send) incomming packet you accept.

This is often called **port forwarding** on web page of router setting.

e.g.

```
ssh (port 22) -> 192.168.1.22
web (port 80&443) -> 192.168.1.80
Foo (port 12345, 666, 1756) -> 192.168.1.100
etc
```

(*) a common objection is:

> But can't my router scan local IPs for open 22 port and update port forwarding ?

**No**, as told above, the router can't guess if you are willing to accept incomming  connection (to put alone time spent to scan your open port).

Comment: At a single point of time i will use either my android or my pc . Not both . In such case how shall the router get confused?

Comment: Port 22 is open

Comment: @Joe_Vj_95 are you sure that your router isn't using ssh (tcp/22) itself, rather than forwarding it on? Some routers do that by default. Cisco Linksys RV042 and Draytek Vigor routers, for example.

Comment: im not sure because im new to networking . how can i check it @roaima

Comment: @Joe_Vj_95 you need to log in to your Router and look at the Maintenance / Administration page.